# xbindkeys scripts to toggle WiFi and Bluetooth devices ON/OFF

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, scripts

I need scripts for toggling WiFi and bluetooth (2 scripts) on/off. I want to use them with `xbindkeys`. I searched the web, but failed to find it. I have found a script for WiFi about a year ago, but I can't find it now, I guess it's removed.

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle: (`<id>` is 2 as example asus-wlan)

```
if [ $(cat /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill2/soft) -eq 1 ]; then rfkill unblock 2; else rfkill block 2; fi
```

(`<id>` is 3: asus-bluetooth)

```
if [ $(cat /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill3/soft) -eq 1 ]; then rfkill unblock 3; else rfkill block 3; fi
```

To see device list (first number to the left is the device `id`):

```
rfkill list
```

Turn off:

```
rfkill block <id>
```

Turn on:

```
rfkill unblock <id>
```

Update: This worked for me well with Ubuntu 12.04 (`dell-wifi`). Now with Ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't. A quick alternative for WiFi is the CLI of `networkmanager`

```
if [ $(nmcli nm wifi | grep -c enabled) -eq 1 ]; then nmcli nm wifi off; else nmcli nm wifi on; fi;
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. I don-t want to have 2 buttons for on and off, I want to have only one for on and off!

Comment: @DušanMilosevic sorry, I miss the word toggle.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but it still doesn't work. When I press f2(which I mapped to this script), it does nothing. I ran xbindkeys-config and when I clicked "run action" I saw that it needs administrator premission. The script I saw a year ago, didn't have that problem. You just press f2 and wifi turns on/off. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: I'm using 14.04. It doesn't request any superuser permission. Could you add `rfkill list` results to your question. To investigate, try running `cat /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/soft` and `rfkill unblock 0` directly within a terminal. If it does not request permission try the whole command and see if it work in terminal.

Comment: **0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
**

Comment: Strange, the script doesn't need superuser, but when i run it with xbndkeys it does need superuser permission. Maybe I have problem with folder permissions.

Comment: Does it toggle wifi in terminal? try with `id=2`. I have updated the answer. As may be  we shouldn't use `phy` directly.

Comment: It works now, I don't know what I did, but it works. Can you make one for bluetooth?

Comment: You will need to replace `rfkill` with `sudo rfkill` for blocking and unblocking. Add `/usr/sbin/rfkill` to sudoers if you don't want to enter your password every time. `<id>` is `bluetooth` for bluetooth. Just type `rfkill` at the terminal to get a list of all `<id>s` .